# Connect clients to Azure Virtual Network (point to site)

Tags: vpn, azure, virtual-network

I'm started using the Azure Virtual Network (Point-to-Site), I successfully implemented the VPN and I can connect from my Windows 8 to a Virtual Machine.

Now I want to connect several users (no technical users) to the VPN, but, I'm lost with the certificate thing, I have to do the "makecert" on all end-user terminals? O exist a simpler way, any idea?

What I want is to tell the users, run this, run this, connect to vpn, ready, it is possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to the Azure VPN network using a Point-To-Site configuration, you need two things:

- Install a **PFX certificate** on the client computers connecting to Azure
- **Create a VPN connection profile** on your computers that will be used to connect to the Azure network, Azure is nice enough to provide and automated .exe file that you can send to you users so they can create
  the connection.

You don't need to use the "**Makecert**" command at each and every computer that will connect to the Azure network, the command is only used to generate the PFX certificate, it's your job to install the certificate on the computers that you want to connect to Azure, there are different ways to do this:

- Create a "**Import-PfxCertificate**" PowerShell script to install the
  PFX certificate, you can use Group Policy to make the script run at
  login if you have a domain, you can ask your users to only install
  the Azure connection profile downloaded from the Azure portal.
- Create your own connection profile using the "**Connection Manager Administration Kit (CMAK)**", this tool that comes for free with you Windows will allow you to create an installer file similar
  to the one that you download from Azure, the difference between this and the Azure VPN installer is that you can add your own custom actions during the connection installation process, one of those
  custom actions can be using a PowerShell script to install the PFX certificate for your users.

References:

- Import-PfxCertificate: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848625.aspx
- Assign Users Logon Scripts: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781361(v=ws.10).aspx (virtually the same for Windows 2012/R2 if you have those)
- Connection Manager Administration Kit: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc752995.aspx
- CMAK Add Custom Actions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732766.aspx